# why i am getting undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to make popover using angular UI  pop over .I load my html and complile that HTml but when I run my program and click ICon (star icon where I am showing pop over ) I am getting error  undefined is not a function?

http://plnkr.co/edit/o0mVZujOH0Apqurvq9xX?p=preview

I used these lines

```
     <td ><span   pop-over items="items", title="Mode of transport" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star content"></span> </td>

app.directive('popOver', function ($compile) {
  var itemsTemplate ="<div ng-controller='AfterCtrl'><ul class='list-group'><li class='list-group-item' ng-click='editRowName()'>Edit</li><li class='list-group-item ' ng-click='deleteRow($index)'>Delete</li></ul></div>" ;
  var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
    var template = '';
    switch (contentType) {
      case 'items':
        template = itemsTemplate;
        break;
    }
    return template;
  }
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    transclude: true,
    template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var popOverContent;
      if (scope.items) {
        var html = getTemplate("items");
        popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);
      }
      var options = {
        content: popOverContent,
        placement: "bottom",
        html: true,
        title: "aa"
      };
      $(element).popover(options);
    },
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      title: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: you double imported jquery

Comment: Line 49 in pop.js is your problem `$(element).popover(options);` popover maybe should be popOver ? or something.. what do you want to do with this line?

Comment: Where is your popover funtion?

Comment: it is internal function bootstap

Comment: When I remove jquerry it show title but not HTML contend edit ot delete

Comment: @Admit I am able see pop over but only title .not inner html

Comment: please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/0shapGvYfuxgcL3aTX3i?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is due to your importing jQuery again at the bottom (as others have already mentioned).
So, remove the last jQuery import.

The main issue is that `scope.items` is undefined, so you never get inside the `if` and thus `popOverContent` remains undefined.
You probably mean to use:

```
...
$scope: {
    items: '@',
    ...
}
```

---

See, also, this **[modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlL3Lb6GFMVs1QTh0aHC?p=preview)**.

---

<sub>Not directly related to the question, but here is a **[modified implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlL3Lb6GFMVs1QTh0aHC?p=preview)** of the `popOver` directive. I have changed it a bit (to make it working with as little changes as possible), e.g. it doesn't have an isolate scope any more, it doesn't use a fixed template etc.

The buttons are working as expected.</sub>

Comment: can you just give more information how I will edit the name of row using popover option and delete row.If you check there is buttons edit and delete .it works fine

Comment: but I need to do same this with popover options to edit the name of row and delete the roe

Comment: if you know any information how to edit the name of row and delete the row please post that anser with plunker I will accept your anser

Comment: The popOverContent contains `ngClick`s (with `editRowName()` and `deleteRow()`), but there are no such function on the scope (because it is an isolate scope). You could pass the function to the isolate scope via attributes and the `&` binding. Take a close look at the **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)**.